# I Deleted my own SID from the Registry

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, login, logging, sid

Just I deleted my own SID from the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList) in windows 2008 R2 server then I logged off. Now tried to log in but getting the below error:

> The user profile service failed the logon. user profile cannot be
>   loaded .

Please any one advice me, how can I get into the server.

Advance Thanks/

Comment: Retore from backup. You have a backup right?

Comment: Use another account/restore from backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, removing the SID-named key from the ProfileList does not do all that much of harm - it just removes the association between the user and her on-disk profile copy. If the user has a roaming profile defined, it is simply re-loaded from the profile path upon next logon and stored in a different local directory in `C:\Users`. If the user has a local profile, it is created anew in a different directory. Windows detects the presence of a conflicting directory in C:\Users and generates new names (e.g. by appending `.<DOMAINNAME>` to the user name).

To troubleshoot why this process might be failing, try logging on with a different (maybe even a newly created) user interactively. Note that a Windows Server also has a whole bunch of remote administration features where the user's profile is not involved (and which would be unaffected by a possible profile corruption):

- you can view event logs from any Windows host using the eventvwr.msc and the [***"connect to another computer" feature***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786582%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- you can do the same with the Computer Management snapin (compmgmt.msc)
- you can connect to the remote computer's registry by using `regedit`
- you can get through to the remote command line by using [***`psexec`***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)
- you can install the [***RSAT***](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) (Windows 7) or the appropriate management features (another Server 2008 R2 machine) to manage roles, features and Active Directory remotely
- [after enabling PS remoting](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) you can run remote PowerShells
- you can access the administrative shares using the `\\servername\C$` notation. From there, you even can access shadow copies (aka "previous versions") of your files - especially `%windir%\system32\config\SOFTWARE` where the HKLM\Software subkey would be stored. You could load a copy of a previous version of this file into regedit [***using the "Load Hive" function***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759303%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and restore the ProfileList entry to its previous state, if necessary.

Note that not all of this functionality will be available if you do not have a domain (or are not using a domain member to connect), also Windows Firewall settings might prevent you from doing one thing or the other remotely.